# Let $X$ a space and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ such that $H_1(f; \mathbb{Z}_2) = 0$. Then $H_2(f; \mathbb{Z}_2) = 0$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

As the title says, I have to show that, given a space $X$ and a map $f: X \to \mathbb{R}P^2$ such that $H_1(f; \mathbb{Z}_2) = 0$, this implies that $H_2(f; \mathbb{Z}_2) = 0$.

This is what I've done so far: since $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field, from the UCT we get that, for any space $Y$ and any $i \geq 0$, $H^i(Y; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(H_i(Y; \mathbb{Z}_2), \mathbb{Z}_2)$.

By the naturality of the exact sequence in the UCT, we get that if $f_\ast = H_1(f; \mathbb{Z}_2) = 0$, then also $f^\ast: H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}_2) \to H^1(X; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is zero.

We know moreover that $H^2(\mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is generated by $\alpha^2$, where $\alpha \in H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is a generator. The naturality of the cup product implies then that the induced map $f^\ast: H^2(\mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}_2) \to H^2(X; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is such that $f^\ast(\alpha^2) = f(\alpha)^2=0$.

By using the UCT again, we have that
$$
    (f_\ast)^\ast: \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(H_2(\mathbb{R}P^2; \mathbb{Z}_2), \mathbb{Z}_2) \to \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_2}(H_2(X; \mathbb{Z}_2), \mathbb{Z}_2)
$$
is zero.

**My question is**: is this enough to conclude that $f_\ast = 0$? In general, it doesn't seems true to me that $(f_\ast)^\ast = 0$ implies $f_\ast = 0$. If not, how can I conclude? Thanks!

Comment: How about using Poincare duality? ($\mathbb{RP}^2$ isn't orientable over $\mathbb{Z}$, but any space is orientable over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is true. The more general statement is that for a linear homomorphism $f\colon V\to W$ of vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over any field $k$ (which is $\mathbb Z_2$ here), if $f^*\colon W^*:=\hom_k(W,k)\to V^*$ is zero, then so is $f$.

Indeed, suppose $f\ne0$, so there is some $v\in V$ with $f(v)\ne0$. Then there is a linear homomorphism $w^\vee\in W^*$ such that $w^\vee(f(v))\ne0$ (e.g., by completing $f(v)$ to a $k$-basis of $W$). But $w^\vee\circ f=f^*(w^\vee)=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! This doesn't hold if $k$ is not a field, right? Like $f^\ast: \text{Hom}(B, \mathbb{Z}) \to \text{Hom}(A, \mathbb{Z})$, where $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups.

Comment: Yes, take $A=B=\mathbb Z/2$